# Dynamically generate the name of the print variable

Tags: php

=I need to print "target Value" in both variants (one-dimensional and two-dimensional array). By dynamically generate the name of the print variable.
I found info on the subject but everything here is about simple variables. but, in my case, I have to use an array.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Something like that, here's my code...

```
    //case One
        $array = [
            0 => 'value',
            1 => 'value',
            2 => 'targetValue'
        ];

    //case Two
        $array = [
            0 => [
                0 => 'value',
                1 => 'value',
                2 => 'targetValue',
            ],
            1 => [
                0 => 'value',
                1 => 'value',
                2 => 'targetValue',
            ],
            2 => [
                0 => 'value',
                1 => 'value',
                2 => 'targetValue',
            ]
        ];

        if(array is two-dimensional){
            $name = 'array[0][2]';
        }else{
            $name = 'array[2]';
        }
        echo $$name;




EXAMPLE 2
$params['criteria'] = 'TargetValue';
$name = "['criteria']";
$test = "Params" . $name;

var_dump($$test);
result:Undefined variable: params['criteria'] (without "$" -
```

I do not know why)

```
OR EXAMPLE 3
$params['criteria'] = 'TargetValue';
$name = "params['criteria']";

var_dump($$name);
result:Undefined variable: params['criteria'] (without "$" -
```

I do not know why)

Is this possible?

Comment: use [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), i.e `if (is_array($array[0])`

Comment: Thanks, but my problem Is how to generate array variable name.  Last line throw me undefine variable:  array

Comment: like this https://3v4l.org/kFBDUv

Comment: You cannot access arrays or object properties using *variable variables*. You would need to use `eval`, though that should be considered wisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE) {
    $name = $array[2];
} else {
    $name = $array[0][2];
}

echo $name;
```

(updated)

I think what you want is something like this example:

```
$params['criteria'] = 'TargetValue';
$name = ${'params'}['criteria'];
var_dump($name);
```

This will return: `string(11) "TargetValue"`

---

Then it's a mix of both, assuming you initial arrays (case 1 and 2)

```
if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE) {
    $name = ${'array'}[2];
} else {
    $name = ${'array'}[0][2];
}

var_dump($name);
```

Comment: Result is string, I need to print targetValue

Comment: I'm confused, this will print the value of the $name. The $name has the value of the $array[2] or $array[0][2] which is "targetValue" and this is based on your question. 
Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I will simplify the example.
Look again please

Comment: I can't change the name of the variable, so I'm looking for a way to generate the name dynamically.

Comment: In this example, the key is always one. But what I need is the following: If the array is two dimensional I have to add one more key to the variable name dynamically. In the end, I have to print "target Value" in both variants (one-dimensional and two-dimensional array)

Comment: @TihomirMinev See my comment above. What you want is syntactically not possible with php. The only way would be to use `eval` or writing a parser. Like [`PropertyAccess`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) for example.

Comment: I guessed it wasn't possible, but I had to ask. I'm looking for the best way to write the code. Thank you for your time!